# Python. Как сделать доп.проверку boolean в течении определенного времени (секундомером)?

Tags: python, selenium

Совсем зеленый, столкнулся с проблемой. Как можно сделать дополнительную проверку,
что **если А==Б в течении 3 секунд**(т.е отсчет времени или начало секундомера именно в момент А==Б) ...(next code). Проблемы с пониманием time.time() . Пробовал вставлять в разные места, но так и не смог достичь результата(не понимаю в каком фрагменте его вставлять и как его прописать). На просторах предлагают громоздкие коды для выполнения (на мой взгляд простого действия). Есть варианты это реализовать и не сильно мудрено? Дополнительная проверка нужна в цикле **if**. Нужно для динамической подгрузки сайта. Менять переменную  *scrool_pause* - не вариант.

```
scrool_pause = 0.5

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(15, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    
    time.sleep(scrool_pause)

    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")


    if new_height == last_height and 'БОЛЬШЕ 3 СЕКУНД':
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте переменную counter и каждую секунду добавляйте ей значение.

что то в духе:

```
time.sleep(scrool_pause)
new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
counter+=1
if new_height!=last_height:
     counter=0

if counter>6:
break
```

Обращаю внимание что каунтер растет только если у нас новый параметр соответствует старому, поэтому если будет несоответствие counter обнулится и отсчет пойдет заново.

P.S я тоже зеленый)

Comment: Очень даже помогло, Спасибо. Ед. что , надо было перед циклом while обозначить просто #counter = 0